How to set a reminder in store procedure using sql server?
I have a query, but want to create a store procedure that will set a reminder if 'Stock on Hand is 0' 'Blank' The following columns(Crystal, Cylical) needs to set a reminder to a recipient via email to action on them once if its blank or 0.
// sql query from the database
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Prepare the email body with the list of items having Stock on Hand = 0
SET @body = N'<h2>Stock Alert: Items with zero stock on hand</h2><table border="1">
               <tr>
                 <th>StockCode</th>
                 <th>Description</th>
                 <th>Warehouse</th>
                 <th>QtyOnHand</th>
                 <th>QtyAllocated</th>
                 <th>QtyOnOrder</th>
                 <th>QtyInTransit</th>
                 <th>QtyOnBackOrder</th>
               </tr>';

-- Add the rows to the email body
SELECT @body = @body + N'<tr>
                         <td>' + InvWarehouse.StockCode + N'</td>
                         <td>' + InvMaster.Description + N'</td>
                         <td>' + InvWarehouse.Warehouse + N'</td>
                         <td>' + CAST(InvWarehouse.QtyOnHand AS NVARCHAR) + N'</td>
                         <td>' + CAST(InvWarehouse.QtyAllocated AS NVARCHAR) + N'</td>
                         <td>' + CAST(InvWarehouse.QtyOnOrder AS NVARCHAR) + N'</td>
                         <td>' + CAST(InvWarehouse.QtyInTransit AS NVARCHAR) + N'</td>
                         <td>' + CAST(InvWarehouse.QtyOnBackOrder AS NVARCHAR) + N'</td>
                         </tr>'
FROM sysproR.dbo.InvMaster InvMaster
JOIN sysproR.dbo.InvWarehouse InvWarehouse
ON InvMaster.StockCode = InvWarehouse.StockCode
WHERE InvWarehouse.QtyOnHand = 0;

-- Close the HTML tags
SET @body = @body + N'</table>';

-- Check if there are items with zero stock on hand
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sysproR.dbo.InvWarehouse
    WHERE QtyOnHand = 0
)
BEGIN
    -- Send the email
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'Test', -- Replace with your Database Mail profile name
         @recipients = 'training@metrocon.com', 
         @subject = 'Stock Alert: Items with zero stock on hand',
         @body = @body,
         @body_format = 'HTML';
END


Why don't you use SQL Server Agent jobs?
SQL Server Agent jobs to schedule tasks that can send reminders. These jobs can execute stored procedures or scripts at specified times, and these scripts can include logic to send reminders based on data in your database.
OR
Use external systems or services that specialize in reminders and notifications. These systems can be triggered by events in your database, such as the completion of a task or a certain date/time being reached.

is there any open source for this i can relate with steps in sql server?

I didn't get what open source you are looking for but I have my own reminders setup in stored procedure and are triggered using SQL server agent job. The job runs every 30 mins and based on that mails are sent. You can refer this article to understand and create the SQL server agent jobs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver16
for creating job: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver16
